# Still no way to integrate WDK 8 into VisualC++ 2012 express edition?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, wdk

I'm using windows 8 64 bit and Visual C++ 2012 express. I came across info that programs using WDK 8 can be built only with professional and above editions. Is that still true?
Anyway, I really want to learn it so I guess that my only option would be to downlaod WDK 7. How much does it differ from WDK 8? Can I create similarily powerful applications, using WDK 7 on windows 8?

Comment: WDK 7 and WDK 8 differ in some things, but drivers/applications built with it will work on newer systems. You only loose some newer APIs. But you shouldn't use the WDK to build applications. It is geared towards driver programs and some support API elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The WDK is still a plugin for Visual Studio, and so does not install without a professional version of Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

WDK 8.1 now runs on VS Express 2013!

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn653318(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn653318%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

http://www.osronline.com/article.cfm?article=620